# javascript - consolidate multiple null/undefined checks

Tags: javascript

My brain is fried from looking from looking at this for so long.  Is there a more efficient way to do this code block.  We have the ability to use es6 code too if that helps.

First it tries to set quantity to `itemTemplateIDQty.value` if `itemTemplateQty` is not valid and `itemTemplateIDQty` is valid.  Then it basically checks the opposite and sets quantity to `itemTemplateQty.value`.  I'm thinking since in that else block, I am simply checking the exact opposite, I shouldn't need to retype all that code again.  Also I'm wondering if I can remove a lot of code by using something like `quantity = itemTemplateIDQty.value || 1;`.

**Update**
I'll try to sum up the code more clearly.  The default value for `quantity` should be 1 if all the checks fail.  First if there are no classes of `itemTemplateQty` found and 1+ classes of `'itemTemplateQty' + itemId` found then set quantity to the value of the first class found of `'itemTemplateQty' + itemId`.  If that check fails, then check if no classes of `'itemTemplateQty' + itemId` are found and 1+ classes of `itemTemplateQty` are found, set `quantity` to the value of the first class of `itemTemplateQty`.

```js
let itemId = 5;
let isDynamicRecommendation = false;
let itemTemplateQty =
        document.getElementsByClassName('itemTemplateQty').length > 0 ? document.getElementsByClassName('itemTemplateQty') : null;
    let itemTemplateIDQty =
        document.getElementsByClassName('itemTemplateQty' + itemId).length > 0 ? document.getElementsByClassName('itemTemplateQty' + itemId) : null;
    let quantity = 1;
    if (!isDynamicRecommendation) {
      if ((itemTemplateQty === null || itemTemplateQty.value == null || Number.parseInt(itemTemplateQty.value) <= 0) &&
         (itemTemplateIDQty !== null && itemTemplateIDQty.value !== undefined && itemTemplateIDQty.value !== null && Number.parseInt(itemTemplateIDQty.value) > 0)) {
           quantity = itemTemplateIDQty.value;
      } else if ((itemTemplateIDQty === null || itemTemplateIDQty.value == null || Number.parseInt(itemTemplateIDQty.value) <= 0) &&
        (itemTemplateQty !== null && itemTemplateQty.value !== undefined && itemTemplateQty.value !== null && Number.parseInt(itemTemplateQty.value) > 0)) {
          quantity = itemTemplateQty.value;
      }
    }
console.log("quantity: ", quantity);
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Please add some more information about what this code does and what the objects in it are (preferably with definitions). Don't forget to take the [tour] and have a look at our [help]  which contains a lot on what makes a good question here.

Comment: I added more details to the question.  Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: As Graipher said, you should provide more context for this code — ideally a live demo including the HTML form (press Ctrl-M in the question editor to make one). How many elements of class `itemTemplateQty` and `itemTemplateQty123` should there be? What is the expected behavior if there are none, or if there are more than one?

Comment: Instead of reiterating what the code does, try telling us what goal of the code is, as if talking to a non-technical person.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.getElementsByClassName()` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a single element. You can use bracket notation `[n]` to get an element at index `n` of the collection returned.

One `if` statement can be used to evalaute `!itemData.isDynamicRecommendation`. One `if..else..if` can be used to evaluate `itemTemplateQty[0] && itemTemplateQty[0].value <= 0` or `itemTemplateIDQty[0] && itemTemplateIDQty[0].value <= 0`.

To convert the string `.value` to an integer you can use `+` operator preceding `+itemTemplateQty[0].value.value` or alternatively use `.valueAsNumber`.

```js
let itemData = 5;
let isDynamicRecommendation = false;

let itemTemplateQty = document.getElementsByClassName('itemTemplateQty')[0];
let itemTemplateIDQty = document.getElementsByClassName('itemTemplateQty' + itemData)[0];
let quantity = 1;
if (!isDynamicRecommendation) {
  if (itemTemplateQty && itemTemplateQty.value <= 0) {
    quantity = +itemTemplateQty.value;
  } else if (itemTemplateIDQty && itemTemplateIDQty.value <= 0) {
    quantity = +itemTemplateIDQty.value;
  }
}

console.log({quantity});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want this and the next one to be `||` not `&&`?  `if (itemTemplateQty && itemTemplateQty[0].value <= 0) {`

Comment: @dmikester1 Not sure what you mean?

Comment: the if and else if should have or's not and's I think

Comment: @dmikester1 `if..else` could essentially be considered an OR gate. The code could be re-written many different ways. For example, conditional operator could be substituted for `if` and `if..else`.  One issue with the code at the question was not using bracket notation to get a specific element in the returned collection, resulting in false positive results. Is `quantity` expected to be an integer or a string?

Comment: `quantity` should be an integer

Comment: @dmikester1 The string returned by `.value` of a `DOM` element can be converted to an integer using the `+` operator. Alternatively you can use `.valueAsNumber`.

Comment: so both those inner if and else if checks will handle null and undefined values for `itemTemplateQty` and `itemTemplateQty.value` and `itemTemplateIDQty` and `itemTemplateIDQty.value` ?

Comment: Basically if all 4 of those variables/objects are any combination of null and/or undefined, `quantity` will drop through and remain 1?

Comment: @dmikester1 Given that the code at the question uses `.getElementsByClassName()`, `document.getElementsByClassName('itemTemplateQty')[0]` returns `undefined` if the element is not in the `document`. If an element does not have a `.value` an empty string `""` is returned, which evaluates "falsey". Why would `"null"` be the `.value` of the element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88706/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1):

Without the HTML it is hard to workout what is wanted.

## General point

- Use `const` for variables that do not change.
- Use functions to do common tasks, they simplify the code by reducing its size.
- Don't test more that you need to. If a is true then you know its not false, you don't then test if its not false.
- The statement `if (!isDynamicRecommendation) {` is always true and not needed. (A reminder that at codeReview code must not be example code, we assume this is production code)
- Use `querySelector` if you are after just the first instance of an element. It returns `null` if nothing is found.
- The code given should be as a function.
- Names ar poor and too verbose. We read words by their shape especially when they are more than half a dozen characters long. Long names means it's hard to spot errors. This is especially bad in JS as it does not care if you use an undefined variable names.

  - `itemTemplateQty` and `itemTemplateIDQty` if you have a single line with these variables repeated 7 times. Can you spot the error in the following?  `itemTemplateQty, itemTemplateQty, itemTemplateQty, itemTemplateIDQty, itemTemplateIDQty, itemTemplate1DQty, itemTemplateIDQty`

    You know its an `item`. the `template` part is irrelevant, the only important part is to differentiate the ID (BTW `Id` should have a lowercase `d`), `qty` and `qtyId` would be better.

    Now spot the same error `qty, qty, qty, qtyId, qtyId, qty1d, qtyId`
  - `itemId`??? Have no idea what this actually is?

### Example

By using two functions we can greatly reduce the complexity of the code. Removing the overly verbose names also make things easier on the eyes, and helps prevent brain fry.

```
function getQuantity() {
    const query = id => document.querySelector(".itemTemplateQty" + id);
    const valid = item => item && !isNaN(item.value) && Number(item.value) > 0.5;
    const qty = query(""), qtyId = query("5");
    return Math.round(valid(qty) ? 
         (!valid(qtyId) ? qty.value : 1) : 
         ( valid(qtyId) ? qtyId.value : 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  These tips help a ton.  I set `itemId` and `isDynamicRecommendation` arbitrarily just to get a working example like was asked.  They are actually passed in variables from the calling function.

Comment: Can you explain the return statement in detail?  That looks very complicated to me.

Comment: @dmikester1 It a ternary expression. Same as the following statement `if (valid(qty)) { if (! valid(qtyId)) { return Math.round(qty.value) } else if (valid(qtyId)) { return Math.round(qtyId.value) } return 1;` For more on ternaries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator